# Git rebase infinite loop with several hundred commits and never up-to-date

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-merge, rebase

I have been working on a feature branch for couple of months and ended up with several hundred commits. I ran `git rebase` and went through few hundred resolutions and it finally synced up. I then ran `git rebase origin/master` again and it started all over again and I persisted and resolved conflicts and completed the process.

Out of curiosity I tried `git rebase origin/master` again with `-i "git rebase -i HEAD~211"` as I have 211 commits that I want to squash but it's asking me to go through same process again i.e. resolve all conflicts.

Could someone offer advice what I'm doing wrong here? How can I get to a point where it says rebase not needed. When I run git merge origin/master it suggests its up-to-date and that's what I want for rebase. I don't want to push my feature branch into master with hundreds of commits in history. There are 4 files that keep repeating in the conflict resolutions. I have a backup for them.

I have been doing git add/rm file-name and git rebase --continue etc but its endless.

Should I have been rebasing regularly like everyday to avoid this?

```
git rebase master
git rebase origin/master
git rebase -i HEAD~211

git add file-name
git rm/add file-name
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you want to rebase instead of merge your changes into master ?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. basically my question is why every time i run git rebase it starts the whole process again and asks me to resolve conflicts? My other question is that why merge works but rebase kicks of conflict resolution?

Comment: Because rebase will change the root of the branch you created to the last commit (or a specific commit) of the branch you want to rebase from. Master won't have your changes made in the subbranch. Merge will put your change into master.

Answer (score 2):

> every time i run git rebase it starts the whole process again and asks me to resolve conflicts

That, and everything else you're saying, is completely normal if you keep rebasing a long-lived branch. You can ease the rebase conflict resolution path with `git rerere` — that is what it's for. You show it once how to resolve the conflicts and it remembers next time.

Personally, though, I recommend *reverse merging* — that is, merge `master` into the long-lived branch to keep it up to date. Once a week is enough. That way, conflicts are much less likely, and if there is one, you resolve it once and done, you'll never see that one again. The structure of your eventual PR will not be materially affected.

Comment: OK, just to understand "reverse merging". the process i'm following is as below. In my VS Code i change to local "master" and pull latest from "origin/master" then i change back to my "feature branch" and run sync to sync up with "master" i then run "git rebase origin/master" when in my feature branch that kicks off the rebase conflict resolution. Could you confirm that you mean by reverse merging is the way i'm doing or merging in the opposite direction i.e. "origin master" which is subject to PR approval.

Comment: Neither. I said, quite clearly, "merge master into the long-lived branch." So, I mean stay on your feature branch and just say `git fetch; git merge origin/master`. (Also I recommend deleting your local `master`, it does nothing for you.)

Comment: OK, i want to squash all my 200 or so commits into single commit before my "long lived branch" can be merged into "origin master". when i run "git rebase -i HEAD~211" it kicks off the same few hundred conflict resolutions. would you suggest "git merge --squash" instead? also one thing i failed to understand that conflicts to be resolved are like 500 plus and commits are 211. which is kind of confusing

Comment: "OK, i want to squash all my 200 or so commits into single commit before my "long lived branch" can be merged into "origin master"" Fine, but that's a completely different question. Let's cross that bridge when we come to it. _This_ question was about the procedure to be following while the long lived branch lives, before we ever reach the point of merging it. I've given my answer to that.